# Where to download VMware workstation for Linux?

Tags: linux, vmware, download

Where can I download VMware workstation for Linux for free?

Comment: What distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From VMware: [VMware Workstation 7.0](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_downloads/vmware_workstation/7_0)

It is not free, though.

Comment: If you want something like that for free try Sun's Virtual Box http://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: VMWare Workstation is not free. VMWare Player is, but you still need to register. @bryan: VirtualBox is good, but slower than VMWare.

Comment: [VMWare Server](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_server/2_0) is also free.

Comment: and the dedicated server version: VMware ESXi